# add padding to an element without moving the rest of them

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have to highlight some elements in my page, it depends on user action,.

I'm doing it adding and remove the higlight class, this highlight class add background and padding.

The problem is with padding and fxFlex elements, the rest of the elements are moved when adding the class:

```
.my-highlighted {
    background: red;
    padding: 2px; //thats my problem
}
```

how can I add a "padding effect" without afect the rest of the elements? I tried border and have the same issue

Comment: `box-sizing: border-box`?

Comment: Try using `box-sizing`

Comment: Try giving fix width to the element you want add the highlight class with box-sizing:border-box; so when the "highlight" class added it will not increase the width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The box-sizing property defines how the width and height of an element are calculated: should they include padding and borders, or not.[more..](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp)

```
* {box-sizing: border-box;}
```

OR

```
.my-highlighted {box-sizing: border-box;}
```